# Check 24-hour clock in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Are there any way to determinate if the user has set the "24-hour clock" setting to true in date+time setting on the Windows Phone 8?

`DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern` property not work because it's only check the country:

> DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern values do not change when the clock is set to 24 hours. The property values should become "h:mm" but remain "h:mm tt" where tt is AM or PM.

Thanks

Comment: where is that documented?

Comment: The documentation is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: That question has more than one year and the Windows Phone version is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 24 hour clock setting in system is a "visual" one. it doesn't alter the culture selected, so you can't know if the user selected it or not. I think, the best solution is to stick to the selected culture.